# reset form method value to default when page refreshes

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

> login.html

```
<form action="/login" method="post" name="login" id="login">
   <input autocomplete="off" id="username" name="username" value="{{ hold }}" type="text">
   <input id="password" name="password"  type="password">
   <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

In above I have press `submit` button, while `username` is empty.

Then form submit with the `post` method and `return render_template("login.html", xvalue=2)` have executed.

After that I have refresh the login web page and I expect the `request.method` been assumed as default (`get`) and `return render_template("login.html", xvalue=4)` get executed.

But `xvalue=2` passed, while the form method value is remained post.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():    
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return render_template("login.html", xvalue=2)
        else:
            return render_template("login.html", xvalue=3)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html", xvalue=4)
```

How can form method variable gets default `get` value, in case of page refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i tried and it seemd to work

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():    
if request.method == "POST":
    if not request.form.get("username"):
        return render_template("login.html", xvalue=2)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html", xvalue=3)
elif request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("login.html", xvalue=3)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Your answer not work. I have revise and edited my question. The false was there. in fact the `elif` not execute and also `request.method` has remains in memory after page refreshed .